# How to remove /bin from egit versioning after accidentally including it. .gitignore isn't working.

Tags: android, eclipse, egit

Using Eclipse Juno, with android development.  Somehow I stupidly included my /bin directory in a egit commit, and now, despite that fact that /bin is in my .gitignore.. egit keeps trying to include the updated files in my /bin directory.  I have right clicked on bin and tried, 'remove from index','ignore', and 'untrack' but alas.. everytime I commit.. the files that changed in bin are sitting there waiting for me to check them off for commit.  This is growing very tiresome, especially since the list of files in /bin is getting bigger and BIGGER.  I use egit only, and would like to stay away from a git command prompt if I can..  All help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `.gitignore` is only for ignoring *untracked* files, not for files which are already committed. That's why adding it to `.gitignore` does not have any effect (except for new files in that folder).

Answer (score 8):

1. Remove 'bin' from gitignore
2. git rm -f bin
3. commit
4. add 'bin' back to gitignore

Comment: I'm using egit.. I am not sure where I would enter git rm -f bin.   Is there a way to get a command prompt inside of eclipse?

Comment: Okay.  It appears untrack is equivalent to rm but this doesn't work.  I may be the victim of this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=363405 which doesn't appear even being worked on.  If anyone has a solution... well.. that would be awesome.

Comment: @ToddPainton, well, you might just get git commandline (msysgit on Windows) and fallback to that. This always works :)

Comment: In Eclipse, just delete the `bin` folder, this corresponds to `git rm`. So essentially the answer by hd1 is correct for Eclipse.

Comment: @robinst... Just delete the file from my package explorer but leave the contents on disk?

Comment: Okay, I just tried to delete bin, and eclipse just inserts it again before I can do anything.

Comment: On a Java 15 app with a module, following these instructions leads to the following error: `Launching <App name> has encountered a problem. Cannot connect to VM' And the following message is logged to the console: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module <module name> not found

Comment: I solved the error in my comment above by deleting the project from Eclipse (but not from my local directory) and then reimporting the project.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove bin and then add "bin" to your .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

Given the bug described above.  I think the only solution I have been able to find is to use 'assume unchanged' which appears to work.  Simply right click on /bin and then select team/advanced/assume unchanged and now it appears that bin is not being included on every commit.

Comment: Well. this doesn't work either.  Quite frustrating.  It's back to wanting to include bin.

Answer (score 0):

An correct answer has already been given by Marcin Gal. I stumbled over the same problem and found this post at the first position of my search. But because the question poster asked for a solution with eGit and no command line I wanted to make it up now:

First open the team view in eclipse and select "Git Repositories". Delete the "bin" directory (or any file which you don't want to be versioned anymore). Now commit your changes (the deleted files will be marked with a grey "X"). Finally you have to recompile your project (because you have deleted all binaries, of course). By the way you do not have to remove and reinsert "/bin" in .gitignore, because it only affects files which are not versioned yet. By deleting and recreating the files, they are not versioned and so .gitignore will work with them.

[image: Delete bin in repository manager]
[image: Commit the deleted files]

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, the key is to **disable** the **Build Automatically** option.

1. disable Project -> Build Automatically
2. easily delete the bin folder
3. commit and push to server
4. after that you can re-enable Build Automatically option
5. add bin to git ignore (to avoid commiting it again)